# Xamarin iOS: The constraints adjust differently on different devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nslayoutconstraint

I'm using storyboard to set the constraints for the view. For a view, I set the constraints along the edges of the screen. So the view edge == edge of the screen . This works well for iPhone, 6s,7,7+ but the constraints are off on smaller devices like 4,4s and 5.

Did anyone else face this issue or do you have any suggestions how to resolve it?

FYI: on the storyboard I'm using View as 'Generic' and wAny hAny as 'AnyWidth''AnyHeight'

Comment: Xamrin iOS designer is not so easy for setting constraints i prefer to open and edit your storyboard in xcode .

Comment: Please, take a screenshoot where we can see all constraint properties to check if anything is wrong

Comment: If you didn't set any constraint for the Height or Width that should have worked. Could you show all the constraint you added to the view?